# How to get list of collections whose name matches regex pattern and drop them

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a db with lots of collections, and some are named according to date, yyyy-mm-dd.  I want to drop each one that matches the date pattern.

The mongo shell help doesn't provide much guidance, all I found was `show collections` but there is no allowance for wild cards.

`db.getCollectionNames()` returns an array but I'm not sure how to filter and execute a command thereon.  Oh, for a `find -name -exec`

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out using an arrow function in the filter for matching and forEach for dropping.

```
use mydb;

db.
  getCollectionNames().
    filter( c => c.match("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$")).
      forEach(function(c){db[c].drop()})
```